# TypeScript, generic type with conditional properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
filters: Filters = {
  type: {
    name: 'type',
    type: FilterType.checkbox,
    availableValues: [
      { label: 'test 1', value: 1},
      { label: 'test 2', value: 2}
    ]
  },
  search: {
    name: 'search',
    type: FilterType.text,
  }
}
```

This represent some filters.
I have 2 filters type and a filter could have some extra properties that are required to work.
I would like to type it properly.
The typing depend on the `type` property.

Some ideas? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You ca use an index signature (to allow any key in `Filter`) and a discriminated union type to require extra properties for certain search types:

```
type Filters = {
    [key: string]: {
        name: string,
        type: FilterType.checkbox,
        availableValues: Array<{
            label: string,
            value: number
        }>
    } | {
        name: string,
        type: FilterType.text,
    }
}

enum FilterType {
    checkbox,
    text
}
var filters: Filters = {
    type: {
        name: 'type',
        type: FilterType.checkbox,
        availableValues: [
            { label: 'test 1', value: 1 },
            { label: 'test 2', value: 2 }
        ]
    },
    search: {
        name: 'search',
        type: FilterType.text,
    }
}
```

Or if you want to preserve the keys in the type and use a function you can also write it like this:

```
type Filters = {
    [key: string]: {
        name: string,
        type: FilterType.checkbox,
        availableValues: Array<{
            label: string,
            value: number
        }>
    } | {
        name: string,
        type: FilterType.text,
    }
}
enum FilterType {
    checkbox,
    text
}

function createFilter<T extends Filters>(p: T & { [P in keyof T]: { name : P }}) : T{
    return p
}

var filters =  createFilter({
    type: {
        name: 'type',
        type: FilterType.checkbox,
        availableValues: [
            { label: 'test 1', value: 1 },
            { label: 'test 2', value: 2 }
        ]
    },
    search: {
        name: 'search',
        type: FilterType.text,
    }
});
```

**Note** The mapped type `{ [P in keyof T]: { name : P }}` will enforce the fact that the `name` is the same as the `key` the object is assigned to. Not sure if this desired but it seemed to be the expected usage.

Comment: type Filter<FilterType.checkbox> {
  name: string,
  type: FilterType.checkbox,
  availableValues: Array<{
      label: string,
      value: number
  }>
}

type Filter<FilterType.text {
    name: string,
    type: FilterType.text
}

type Filters = {
  [key: string] : Filter
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to encapsulate the filter types and logic here. I'm guessing the following method might be useful so that you have a generic interface and you can invoke `apply()` method to all your inputs. Although I don't know exactly the use case of it.

```
export interface InputFilter {
  type: FilterType;
  apply: () => boolean;
}

export class CheckboxInputFilter implements InputFilter {
  type = FilterType.checkbox;
  availableValues: { label: string, value: number }[];

  apply(itemThatNeedFilter: any): boolean {
    // use this.availableValues and work out the instance filter result
  }
}

export class TextInputFilter implements InputFilter {
  type = FilterType.text;
  keyword: string;

  apply(itemThatNeedFilter: any): boolean {
    // use this.keyword and work out the instance filter result
  }
}
```